# Android, RecyclerView: Async Loading causes items to double

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my app, I have a `RecyclerView` containing (on my phone) about 700 song titles with band names. Nothing too crazy, but reloading this all on the UI thread caused a little lag. I decided to do the loading in an Asynctask, away from the UI thread. This is what it looks like:

```
 public class PhotoAlbumAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj;
        Context ctx;
        Activity act;
        MediaMetadataRetriever reader;
        DataBase db;
        List<SeekObj> seekObj;
        Typeface tf;
        AudioManager audioManager;


        public PhotoAlbumAdapter(List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Context ctx, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, AudioManager audioManager, Activity act)
        {

            this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.db = db;
            this.seekObj = seekObj;
            this.act = act;
            this.audioManager = audioManager;
            reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

            tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(ctx.Assets, "Baiti.ttf");
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                        Inflate(Resource.Layout.CardView, parent, false);
            PhotoViewHolder vh = new PhotoViewHolder(itemView, mp3Obj, act, reader, db, seekObj, audioManager, ctx);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;



            SetContent(vh, position);


        }

        private async void SetContent(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
        {
            await SetContentAsync(vh, position);
        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {

            get
            {
                if (mp3Obj != null)
                {
                    return mp3Obj.Count();
                }
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        private async Task SetContentAsync(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
        {
            string SongName = "";
            string ArtistName = "";

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
                }
                catch
                {

                }

                SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
                ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);
            });

            ((Activity)ctx).RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
                vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
                vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;
            });
        }
    }
```

This did infact smooth the overall performance up quite a lot but caused some weird side effect:

When I scrolling down the list fast and then stop it appruptley I see the same song 2-3 times in a row. Only one of those items is the song itself, the others are different songs but with the wrong song and artist name on top of them.

If I now scroll up just ever so slightly that the doubling items are out just off the screen and then scroll back the `RecyclerView` seems to have corrected itself and the doubled or sometimes tripled items are gone.

This issue only occurs since I moved the loading into an Async-task. Did I maybe do something wrong here?

Comment: I did not read your code completely. But if you are loading an Image in an ImageView. Then consider using a Image Loading Library like Picasso.

Comment: no imageview loading. just doubled items :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the point here is to keep references of the `viewHolder`.

I would suggest you to try an approach like that:

```
public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvSongName;

    public PhotoViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        //initialize here views; ie
        //this.tvSongName = v.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
    }

    public void initializeAsync(int position) {
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            String songName, otherStuff;

          @Override
          public void run () {
            // here we are async.

            // Retrieve here your song informations, ie:
            //object myRetrievedObject = getSongInfoBasedOnPositionSomeHow(); 
            //songName = myRetrievedObject.retrievedSongName;
            //otherStuff = myRetrievedObject.retrievedOtherStuffs;

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run () {
               // make operation on UI
                tvSongName.setText(songName);
                //...
                //...
             }
            });
          }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

And call this like:

```
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        PhotoViewHolder vh = holder as PhotoViewHolder;
        vh.initializeAsync(position);
    }
```

Please consider that I wrote that without the compiler  so it might be not perfect, let me know in any case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey thank you for the effort, you dont have this in any chance in c#? :)

Comment: @InnomotionMedia you should consider changing the tag in the question, if not specified android is java by default :) It's really similar; I'm not an expert of xamarin so unfortunatly I can't help you with c#

Comment: I shall give it a go soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the arraylist is getting populated twice.so Just before loading arraylist once again in your activity class use yourarraylistname.clear(); to clear the arraylist and then load the data next tym.So whenever you populate the arraylist again it will first get cleared then load the data once again.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really understand. What do you mean? :)

Comment: @InnomotionMedia please check my updated answer , hope you understand.

Comment: thank you. however I can see from my debugger that my list is just fine. it must be the recycler view that confuses the views ...